# Webdynpro: component doesnot merge after migrate

Tags: java, webdynpro

I have component and want to migrate to 7.3. But after migrated, I see 2 components (1 old & 1 new), but I want to only 1 component after migrated. Do you know root cause and best practice to complete?
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be some incompatibility of your component with the new version of Netweaver. Have you followed the procedure of migrating [described here](http://scn.sap.com/community/web-dynpro-java/blog/2013/02/22/migration-of-web-dynpro-java-dcs-from-70-to-731-stepwise-procedure-and-troubleshooting)?
The best you can do here is to test the second (lower) active app, and if it works, to delete the first erroneous one.